# DevOps IIS Web App Deploy XML variable substitution Ignores key named SECRET_KEY

Tags: iis, azure-devops, web-deployment

I have an appSetting named SECRET_KEY. I am unable to get the IIS Web App Deploy task to substitute a key with this name, all my other XML Variable Substitutions work fine.

I have no errors, I can look in the log and see the

> **Processing substitution for xml node : appSettings**

it lists all other appSetting entries that I have variables defined for but nothing listed for SECRET_KEY.

I suspect the issue may be related to the key name, anybody else ran into certain keys not being substituted?

Comment: It looks that you are not first. Please check this [topic](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7194). There is no much info. But issue is similar to your. I checked also developer community, without a luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`secret` is one of variable prefixes that are reserved by the system, please don't use such variable prefixes. Check the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#variable-characters

> User-defined variables can consist of letters, numbers, `.`, and `_`
>   characters. Don't use variable prefixes that are reserved by the
>   system. These are: `endpoint`, `input`, `secret`, and `securefile`.
>   Any variable that begins with one of these strings (regardless of
>   capitalization) will not be available to your tasks and scripts.